# setTimeout not working javascript and svg

Tags: javascript

heres a url to my site granite.sru.edu/~jaw1005/progress.php

The problem is i have 5 svg elements that act as buttons and each button changed the graph.

I want to make a function that is something like this

```
function play(evt){
  setTimeout(doButtons5(evt),3000)
  setTimeout(doButtons4(evt),3000)
  setTimeout(doButtons4(evt),3000)
 }
```

The purpose is to show the change in the data as a animation.

When i click on the black circle which calls the play function nothing happens, so any help would be greatly apprectiated.

Here is a chunk of code dont know if it will help or not

```
function doButtons5(evt){
    http5.open('get',"http://granite.sru.edu/~jaw1005/getdata5.php");
    http5.onreadystatechange = getData5;
    http5.send(null);

}

function getData5(){
   if(http5.readyState == 4){
     sampsonnnn=http5.responseText
     doSVGStuff5(sampsonnnn)

}

}
```

Comment: You are executing `doButtons5` **immediately** and pass the **return value** to `setTimeout`, which is `undefined`. You have to pass a function to `setTimeout`. Please read the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as per the window.setTimeout documentation you have to use timeout like this:

```
function play(evt){
  setTimeout(doButtons5,3000)
  setTimeout(doButtons4,3000)
  setTimeout(doButtons4,3000)
 }
```

Comment: man do i feel stupid sometimes, thanks for the help much appreciated

Comment: is it what you are looking for ?

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing synchronous patterns with asynchronous functions. The first thing I can recommend is to use a good async pattern library like [Q Promises](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) or at the very least [jQuery Deferred](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/). The reason is code readability and coder sanity.

When you call a function like `doButtons5(evt)` it executes immediately and the return value from that call is what is passed to `setTimeout`. Based on the example of the OP I inferred this is not the desired wish. I based that on the use of the passed in `evt` variable which if referenced outside of the `play` function would not exist when `setTimeout` finally calls the callback. The example `doButton5` does not use the passed variable `evt` was it the intent that you need to keep the reference to this object? I'll assume that is the case and show how to use partial applications to facilitate such.

Also, the `doButton5` example looks like it is using a form of XHR which is also asynchronous. Thus the need for `setTimeout` is not needed to defer the execution.

### partial application

```
function bindEvt(fn, evt) {
  // setTimeout does not pass arguments so no need to worry about them.
  return function() {
    fn(evt);
  };
}
```

This will return a new function who has the `evt` variable bound in a closure.

### Helper for setTimeout

Next we need to chain the `setTimeout`s and to make it easy lets write a helper function for this.

```
function asyncFns() {
  // We could pass an array but for now this is good enough.
  var funcs = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
  var timeout = 3000;

  for (var i = 0; i < func.length; i++) {
    setTimeout(funcs[i], timeout);
  }
}
```

And lets refactor the `play` method:

```
function play(evt) {
  asyncFns(
    bindEvt(doButtons5, evt),
    bindEvt(doButtons4, evt),
    bindEvt(doButtons4, evt)
  );
}
```